# Why divider is never displayed in this context

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, divider

I tried to create a custom tab widget in the Flutter app

I would like to have each specific square which contains 1 divider colored and Text layout into a column widget.

My text displays correctly but all tried code never displayed my color blue divider.

I also tried a trick that wrapped Row or Column by Container or IntrinsicHeight like explained here : [Trick to display Divider into Row](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/138/how-to-fix-vertical-divider-not-showing-in-flutter-app/)

I also changed the background color but nothing changed.

Why Flutter refuse to display my Divider widget in this context :

```
class _TabAppState extends State<TabApp>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Container(
      width: 250,
      height: 200,
      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Divider(color: Colors.blue),
              Container(height: 100, child: Column(children: [Divider(color: Colors.blue, height: 25, thickness: 2, indent: 5, endIndent: 5), Text('Tab 1', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge)])),
              SizedBox(height: 100, child: Column(children: [Divider(color: Colors.blue, height: 25, thickness: 2, indent: 5, endIndent: 5)])),
              Column(children: [VerticalDivider(color: Colors.blue, width: 30), Text('Tab 2', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge)]),
              Container(child: Column(children: [SizedBox(height: 10, width: 50), Text('Tab 3', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge)])),
              Container(child: Column(children: [Divider(color: Colors.blue, height: 25, thickness: 2, indent: 5, endIndent: 5)])),
            ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for giving me help or a way to resolve this...

Comment: The main issue is here how constraints is passing down to the Divider widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is here how constraints is passing down to the Divider widget. You can use `VerticalDivider` in Row, and the contains are not getting the proper constraints(width) for Divider widget. you can use several  approach like fixed width, Expanded or `IntrinsicWidth`. Here is the demo

```dart
Container(
  width: 250,
  height: 200,
  color: const Color(0xFF000000),
  child: IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.blue,
          thickness: 2,
        ),
        IntrinsicWidth(
          // or any constraints widget
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  indent: 5,
                  endIndent: 5,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
                Text('Tab 1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I confirm that your solution work in my context and for my requirement. Again and also that you I confirm that need to more understand constraints flutter system.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find [more about constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)